# Work item migration from one {source}.visualStudio.com to {destination}.visualStudio.com

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to migrate workitems from {source}.visualstudio.com to {destination}.visualstudio.com (including attachment(s) tied to the work item)

Is there a tool/process out there to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TFS Integration Platform](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) to migrate work items (with attachments) between two VSO accounts.

You can have a check on this series of blogs on how to use it:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/willy-peter_schaub/archive/2009/10/07/tfs-integration-platform-summary-of-links.aspx

Comment: Just a bit of warning. This tool does work but is old and does not handle all scenarios very well. For example, if you are migrating links it has known scalability issues with them. If you are doing a small migration this will be fine but anything large and you may run into issues.